# Magento2: Knockout JS page in frontend give "404"

Tags: magento2, frontend, knockoutjs

I have followed this tutorial [link](https://magenest.com/en/how-to-use-knockout-js-on-a-magento-2-frontend-page/)

HOW TO USE KNOCKOUT JS ON A MAGENTO 2 FRONTEND PAGE.

> Magenest/KnockoutJs/etc/frontend/routes.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
       <route id="knockout" frontName="knockout">
           <module name="Magenest_KnockoutJs" />
       </route>
   </router>
</config>
```

> Magenest/KnockoutJs/view/frontend/layout/knockout_test_index.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
       <title>Knockout Js Testing Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="content">
           <block class="Magenest\KnockoutJs\Block\Test" name="knockoutjs_test_block" template="test.phtml">
               <arguments>
                   <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="test" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magenest_KnockoutJs/js/view/test</item>
                               <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

> Magenest/KnockoutJs/Block/Test.php :

```
<?php
namespace Magenest\KnockoutJs\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Test extends Template
{
   /**
    * @var array|\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface[]
    */
   protected $layoutProcessors;

   public function __construct(
       Template\Context $context,
       array $layoutProcessors = [],
       array $data = []
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
       $this->jsLayout = isset($data['jsLayout']) && is_array($data['jsLayout']) ? $data['jsLayout'] : [];
       $this->layoutProcessors = $layoutProcessors;
   }

   public function getJsLayout()
   {
       foreach ($this->layoutProcessors as $processor) {
           $this->jsLayout = $processor->process($this->jsLayout);
       }
       return \Zend_Json::encode($this->jsLayout);
   }

}
```

> Magenest/KnockoutJs/Controller/Test/Index.php :

```
<?php
namespace Magenest\KnockoutJs\Controller\Test;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

   protected $resultPageFactory;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
   )
   {
       $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
       parent::__construct($context);
   }

   public function execute()
   {
       $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
       return $resultPage;

   }
}
```

> Magenest/KnockoutJs/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml :

```
<div id="test-div" data-bind="scope:'test'">
   <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
   <script type="text/x-magento-init">
       {
           "#test-div": {
               "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
           }
       }
   </script>

   <script>
       require([
           'mage/url',
           'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
       ], function(url, blockLoader) {
           blockLoader("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>");
           return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
       })
   </script>
</div>
```

> Magenest/KnockoutJs/view/frontend/web/js/view/test.js :

```
define([
   'ko',
   'uiComponent',
   'mage/url',
   'mage/storage',
], function (ko, Component, urlBuilder,storage) {
   'use strict';
   var id=1;

   return Component.extend({

       defaults: {
           template: 'Magenest_KnockoutJs/test',
       },

       productList: ko.observableArray([]),

       getProduct: function () {
           var self = this;
           var serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('knockout/test/product?id='+id);
           id ++;
           return storage.post(
               serviceUrl,
               ''
           ).done(
               function (response) {
                   self.productList.push(JSON.parse(response));
               }
           ).fail(
               function (response) {
                   alert(response);
               }
           );
       },

   });
});
```

> Magenest/KnockoutJs/view/frontend/web/template/test.html :

```
<button data-bind=" click: getProduct">Get Next Product</button>
<table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Product Name</th>
       <th>Product Price</th>
       <th>Preview</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: productList">
   <tr>
       <td data-bind="text: entity_id"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
       <td><img data-bind="attr: {src: src}" width="120" height="150" alt="Product Image"></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

> Magenest\KnockoutJs\Controller\Test\Product.php :

```
<?php
namespace Magenest\KnockoutJs\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   protected $productFactory;
   protected $imageHelper;
   protected $listProduct;
   protected $_storeManager;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
       ProductFactory $productFactory,
       StoreManager $storeManager,
       Image $imageHelper
   )
   {
       $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
       $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       parent::__construct($context);
   }

   public function getCollection()
   {
       return $this->productFactory->create()
           ->getCollection()
           ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
           ->setPageSize(5)
           ->setCurPage(1);
   }

   public function execute()
   {
       if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
           $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);

           $productData = [
               'entity_id' => $product->getId(),
               'name' => $product->getName(),
               'price' => '$' . $product->getPrice(),
               'src' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl(),
           ];

           echo json_encode($productData);
           return;
       }
   }
}
```

Required Result :
[image]

But Getting "404"

Complete Module [Here](https://github.com/hafizjee/knockout-js)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know still, 404 return.

Comment: thank u let me check

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/m2.3.0/knockout/test/index
same "404". no success

Comment: Did you checked after update my answer? Check with cache clean and remove generated folder.

Comment: Now, It's working?

Comment: cache clear but same issue 404 page not found

Comment: Upgrade and deploy then, check in pub/static file available or not.

Comment: pub/static file availabe .

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call your test.js file. Replace this below code in your test.phtml file in your `<script type="text/x-magento-init">..</script>`:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
       "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
                "test-div": {
                    "component": "Magenest_KnockoutJs/js/test"
                }
            }
        }

   }
</script>
```